# Share variables between methods

Tags: c#, variables, methods

This is problably a dumb question but how would I go about sharing the variables ammount and price with the other method?

```
[Command("sellweed")]
public void sellWeed(Client sender, Client target, int ammount, int price)
{
    API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(sender, "~b~You have offered " + ammount + 
        " Weed to " + target + "for $" + price + ", wait for him to accept.");
    API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(target, "~b~" + sender + " has offered you " + ammount + 
        " Weed for a price of $" + price + ", type /acceptweed to buy.");
}

[Command("acceptweed")]
public void acceptWeed(Client player)
{
    checkPlayerName = API.getPlayerName(player);
    string checkMoney = "SELECT Wallet FROM [playerInfo] WHERE PlayerName='" + 
        checkPlayerName + "'";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand checkMoneyCMD = new SqlCommand(checkMoney, con);
    int playerMoney = Convert.ToInt32(checkMoneyCMD.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();
    if (playerMoney < price)
    {
        API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "You don't have enough money.");
    }
    else
        API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "You received " + ammount + " of weed.");
}
```

Comment: Amount only has one `m`

Comment: where is `price` defined (i.e. how does `acceptWeed` have access to that)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally values are passed from one method to another through the arguments list. Just as you are currently passing the `Client player` to the `acceptWeed` method, you could also have `price` and `amount` passed to that method.

You're not showing where this method is called, but presumably it's from somewhere that knows about `price` and `amount`.

Also, you should get in the habit of using parameterized queries. The current syntax you're using could potentially leave you open to SQL injection attacks. I've included that in the answer as well. You can read more about it [HERE](http://bobby-tables.com/).

```
[Command("acceptweed")]
public void acceptWeed(Client player, int amount, int price)
{
    checkPlayerName = API.getPlayerName(player);

    string checkMoney = "SELECT Wallet FROM [playerInfo] WHERE PlayerName = @playerName";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(checkMoney, con))
    {
        var playerName = new SqlParameter("playerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        playerName.Value = API.getPlayerName(player);
        command.Parameters.Add(playerName);

        int playerMoney = Convert.ToInt32(checkMoneyCMD.ExecuteScalar());
    }

    if (playerMoney < price)
    {
        // It might be nice to tell the player how much money they have
        API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "You don't have enough money.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something to subtract 'price' from 'playerMoney'
        // Also do something to subtract 'amount' from the seller's stash
        // And do something to add 'amount' to the buyer's stash
        API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "You received " + amount + " of weed.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make some getters.
ps lol ammount is really spelled amount.

Put this in the function with the variables.

```
public int getAmmount(){
      return ammount;
}
public int getPrice(){
      return price;
}
```

Then in the function you want to retrieve the values from you would use:

```
var amount = sellweed.getAmmount();
```

This sets the variable amount to the value of ammount which is in sellweed.  It goes the same for getPrice.

```
var price = sellweed.getPrice();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be capitlizing the method names?  Naming standards and all..

Comment: @JoshuaSmith He didn't capitalize it in the code.  I'm just doing it to match what he said.